# Overleaf Time out in Lualatex (due to one image)

Tags: luatex, overleaf

I am using a master thesis template in Overleaf (Lualatex compiler) and have trouble with compiling where Overleaf gives a timeout error. I have been looking for fixes online on timeout errors in Overleaf but none of the solutions worked, I have tried:

- compiling without images in the tex files, this works!
- fast draft compiling (does not work)

The problem lies in  the figures it seems but I believe the size of the images can not be the reason for a time out since timeout happens even when compiling with 1 image and when doing a fast draft compiling. If anyone is able to see what is going wrong, I have placed my Overleaf code in the github repository: https://github.com/JulesVandenbroeck/MasterThesisTest.git.

Comment: I won't debug code in an external source, but you could ask the overleaf support for help.

Comment: `lualatex` is slower then `pdflatex` or `xelatex` which probably means you're hitting the Overleaf time out limit. The solution is to either upgrade to a paid membership (free accounts get 1 minute compilation vs 4 minutes for paid) or install a local TeX (TeX Live 2023 etc.). Additionally, this site works best as a helping hand for issues that have a clear question and answer, putting a link to a repository and seeking significant help isn't what this site is for, is it possible to download TeX onto your computer/system?

Comment: Your images add up to around 7 MB of data which is pretty significant for just 11 figures, your `CMS.png` is 4 MB on its own, your image size is likely hitting the time out limit

Comment: On my windows 10 with 12 GB ram, my `lualatex` PhD document with around 30 images, tables and `biber` + `makeglossaries` can take around 7-8 minutes to compile (using `arara`), Overleaf uses `latexmk` which means it sorts out your citations, glossaries and such, you're definitely hitting the timeout limit

Comment: thank you for the answers, would the best course of action be to convert my images to a more compact format such as pdf? and change to a local TeX so the compilation can run longer?

Comment: png graphics cost much time as pdftex has to uncompress and recompress them, jpg or pdf is better.